# Customizing Android sample app

Tags: android, sdk, sample

I'm doing some customizations to this Android sample app: [HoneycombGallery](http://ncc.dlut.edu.cn/course/android/source/docs/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/index.html).

I need to execute some extra code when a user switches betweens the tabs (Balloons - Pastries) but running into some problems here.

What I need to do specifically is to return the name of the tab (the directory categories) *every time* a user switches to a new tab. I need that string in the code I'd like to execute every time a user switches tabs. I can't find a way to dynamically do this, or maybe I'm just trying to do it in the wrong java file.

How would you go about this? Any input greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I need to clarify.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a `onTabSelected()` in your `MainActivity`. Get the tab name/title/text from it.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I had tried it before but my app crashed because the methods I implemented required context. I got the fragment context through getActivity().